# Set default option in dropdown directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a month directive. But I cannot add a default option in that directive because somewhere it is needed and somewhere it is not.

Here is the directive:

```
App.directive('monthdir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template:
            '<option value="1">January</option>' +
            '<option value="2">February</option>' +
            '<option value="3">March</option>' +
            '<option value="4">April</option>' +
            '<option value="5">May</option>' +
            '<option value="6">June</option>' +
            '<option value="7">July</option>' +
            '<option value="8">August</option>' +
            '<option value="9">September</option>' +
            '<option value="10">October</option>' +
            '<option value="11">November</option>' +
            '<option value="12">December</option>'
    };
});
```

And I have add default option but it is not showing. Please help me what should I do.

```
<select ng-model="Month" class="chosen-select input-md" chosen="" ng-required ng-change="ChangeUser()" month-options>
      <option value="" selected="selected">Choose</option>
</select>
```

Comment: $scope.month=1, into the controller,. Take  a default value to the model. And there is a better solution is makin a optons-repeat to the select, given a array of objects. Not using a template

Comment: wich option? use template, and not repeat???

Comment: i need this <option value="" selected="selected">Choose</option> some where or some where not. thats why i dont add this in directive

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert that default option in the template itself.

```js
App.directive('monthdir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template:
            '<option value="1">January</option>' +
            '<option value="2">February</option>' +
            '<option value="3">March</option>' +
            '<option value="4">April</option>' +
            '<option value="5">May</option>' +
            '<option value="6">June</option>' +
            '<option value="7">July</option>' +
            '<option value="8">August</option>' +
            '<option value="9">September</option>' +
            '<option value="10">October</option>' +
            '<option value="11">November</option>' +
            '<option value="12">December</option>'+
            '<option value=" ">Choose</option>'
      
    };
});
```

Comment: i cannot add this option because somewhere we have need this default somewhere not. thats why i want add this option where we need

Comment: @ArsalanQaiser then make it optional in the directive's declaration.

Comment: can u please tell me how can i do this

Comment: You can use ng-if condition for that option value

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario just add it manually through some JavaScript:

```
var option = document.createElement('option');
option.text = 'Choose';
option.selected = 'selected';
var select = document.querySelector('.chosen-select');
select.insertBefore(option, select.childNodes[0]);
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/1sazs191/

Making this option optional in the directive should not be too difficult.